# How can I send back google chart data to google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I was wondering if it is possible to send back user's input from google visualisation (google chart) to google sheet?

For example if a user inputs A and B values, is it possible to send them to google sheet to do an operation.

More concise example:
`A user enters, Rate of Interest, number of period and payment amount. I want to take these inputs and operate pv function in google sheet and then send back the output to the chart`

(send back part I know how to do).

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do, could you elaborate your question? If you want to use a chart inside a Sheet, you can use the EmbeddedChart class [ https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart ]. And please, share the code that you are currently using and the error that it gives you back; that way we all could help you better.

Comment: I want to take the user input data (given on webpage of course) and send it to googlesheet.. then use that data to do complex calculations and resend the data to create a chart at the frontend (webpage).

Answer (score 0):

You can't save userdata introduced on a Chart. As you can read on the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#getting-started), Google Charts…

> …allows you to create charts and reporting applications over
>   structured data and helps integrate these directly into your website.

As a workaround you could ask your users to write on a [Form](https://www.google.com/forms/about/), or you could share a Sheet with them to be filled with your requested data.